# Analogue of continuous mapping theorem for convergence in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Could you help please:

Is there any analogue of continuous mapping theorem for convergence of sequence of random variables in $L^2$?

I mean:
If $g$ is a continuous function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (not differentiable in general) and $X_n \stackrel{L^2} \to X$ then $g(X_n) \stackrel{L^2} \to g(X).$

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is tautologically true

Comment: I suppose $g$ is assumed to be a continuous function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (not a continuous function on $L^2$ as @Norbert seems to assume) and that $g(X_n)$ denotes composition $g \circ X_n$. Dan, could you please clarify?

Comment: Martin, thanks. Surely I assumed $g$ to be continuous $\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: Why would this be tautological?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without further assumptions this is false.  If $g$ is unbounded, we might not even have $g(X_n), g(X) \in L^2$.

If $g$ is bounded and continuous, then $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in measure by the continuous mapping theorem, and also in any $L^p$ by the dominated (bounded) convergence theorem.  So the statement is true in this case.

It also holds when $g$ is unbounded but Lipschitz: if $C$ is the Lipschitz constant, then $g(X_n), g(X) \in L^2$ because $|g(X_n)| \le |g(0)| + C |X_n|$ where the right side is an $L^2$ random variable.  Moreover, we have $$E|g(X_n) - g(X)|^2 \le C^2 E|X_n - X|^2$$ where the latter goes to zero.

Comment: +1. As a side note, there is a section on the book "A Primer in Nonlinear Analysis" by Prodi & Ambrosetti dedicated to those things. Keyword: *Nemitsky operators*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! one last question concerning this problem. Can we say smth about convergence if we know that $g$ - continuous and $g(X_n),g(X)∈L^2,$ but $g$ is not necessarily Lipchitz?

Comment: @Dan: From the already mentioned book by Prodi & Ambrosetti, Remark 2.5 pag. 17, it is possible to show that if $g$ is continuous and $g(X)\in L^2$ for all $X\in L^2$, then the map $X\to g(X)$ is continuous with respect to the $L^2$-norm. Unfortunately the proof is not given.

Comment: @Giuseppe, thanks! They cite Vainberg, M.M., Variational Methods for the Study of Nonlinear operators. I don't have one. Failed to prove it myself. Apparently I have to ask this question separately from the latter one.

Comment: I am not sure if the dominated convergence theorem is applicable here: once you have pulled the limit inside the integral you need $X_n \to X$ point-wise (or almost surely would be enough). But you have $L^2$ convergence.

I mean there might be some clever trick using the fact that $L^2$ conv. implies stochastic convergence which provides an almost surely converging subsequence. But I don't think it is obvious. And I am not sold on that yet.

Comment: @FelixB.: The dominated convergence theorem only needs convergence in measure (by the subsequence trick which you alluded to).

Comment: @NateEldredge how do you deal with the elements not in the subsequence?

Comment: @FelixB.: See the remark under "Proof of the theorem" which says "DCT holds even if fn converges to f in measure (finite measure) and the dominating function is non-negative almost everywhere."  I don't know why they say "finite measure" because that assumption isn't necessary either.

Comment: @FelixB.: The "trick" is something like this.  Suppose $Y_n \to Y$ in measure, $|Y_n| \le Z$ where $Z$ is integrable.  Suppose to the contrary that $E[Y_n]$ does not converge to $E[Y]$.  Then there is a subsequence $Y_{n_k}$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|E[Y_{n_k}] - E[Y]| > \epsilon$ for all $k$.  Now $Y_{n_k} \to Y$ in measure as well, so it has a further subsequence $Y_{n_{k_j}}$ with $Y_{n_{k_j}} \to Y$ almost surely, and still has $|E[Y_{n_{k_j}}] - E[Y]| > \epsilon$ for all $j$.  But by the usual dominated convergence theorem, $E[Y_{n_{k_j}}] \to E[Y]$, contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $g$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, for $\alpha \geq 0$, and that $X_n \overset{L^m}{\to} X$ for some $m > 0$. If $\alpha > 0$, then $g(X_n) \overset{L^{m/\alpha}}{\to} g(X)$. If $\alpha = 0$ (i.e. bounded), and $g$ is continuous, then $g(X_n) \overset{L^m}{\to} g(X)$. The case $\alpha = 1$ corresponds to Lipschitz continuity. The case $\alpha > 0$ is very easy to prove. I'd be interested in more general results.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists constants $c_1$, $c_2$ such that $|g(x)| \leq c_1 + c_2 \cdot |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$, then $g(X_n) \stackrel{L^{2}}{\to} g(X)$.

On a closed and bounded interval $[-M, M]$, $g$ is uniformly continuous. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta(M) > 0$ such that
$$
\text{ if } |X_n - X| < \delta(M), \text{ then } |g(X_n) - g(X)| < \sqrt{\epsilon}
$$
Consider sets of the form
$$
B_n(M) = \{x: |X_n| < M \text{ and } |X| < M\}
$$
$$
A_n(M) = \{x \in B_n(M): |X - X_n| < \delta(M)\}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
E(|g(X_n) - g(X)|^{2}) &= E(|g(X_n) - g(X)|^{2} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_n(M)}) + E(|g(X_n) - g(X)|^{2} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_n(M)^c}) \\
&\leq \epsilon + E(|g(X_n) - g(X)|^{2} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_n(M)^c}) \\
\end{align*}
for all $n$ and $M$.
$\Pr(A_n(M)^c)$ can be made arbitrarily small for big enough $M$ and $n$ using Markov's Inequality and $L^2$-convergence.
The result then follows by showing $\{|g(X_n) - g(X)|^2\}$ is uniformly integrable when the condition on $g$ holds.