# Continuous mapping theorem for convergence in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

This question is related to [Analogue of continuous mapping theorem for convergence in $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423032/70762) but has narrower conditions.

Is it true that:

If

1) $g$- continuous $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ function,

2) random variables $X_n \stackrel{L^2}\to X$ and

3) $g(X_n), g(X) \in L^2$

then $g(X_n) \stackrel{L^2}\to g(X)$ ? If it is then why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To guarantee that the mapping $X\to g(X)$ is $L^2$-continuous you should require that $g(X)\in L^2$ for all $X\in L^2$. That's the condition found in the book by Prodi & Ambrosetti we saw in the other post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $u_n(x) = x^{\alpha_n}/n$ with $\alpha_n = 1/(4\,n)-1/4$.
Finally, take $g(t) = t^2$.

Then,
$$\int_0^1 u_n^2 \, dx = \frac1{(2 \, \alpha_n + 1) \, n} \, [x^{2 \, \alpha_n + 1}]_0^1 = \frac1{(2 \, \alpha_n + 1) \, n} \to 0$$
and
$$\int_0^1 g(u_n)^2 \, dx = \frac1{(4 \, \alpha_n + 1) \, n} \, [x^{4 \, \alpha_n + 1}]_0^1 = \frac1{(4 \, \alpha_n + 1) \, n} = 1.$$
Hence, $u_n \to 0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, but $g(u_n) \not\to g(0)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Note that $g(u_n), g(0) \in L^4(\Omega)$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, @gerw !

Comment: $\int_0^1 u_n^2dx =\int_0^1 x^{2\alpha_n}/n^2dx=\frac{1}{n^2} \left[\frac{1}{2\alpha_n+1}x^{2\alpha_n+1}\right]_0^1 =\frac{1}{(2\alpha_n+1)n^2}$ and with $\sqrt{n}$ it still results in $n^2$ in the second case. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it should be $u_n(x) = x^{\alpha_n}/\sqrt{n}$. Then, the calculation with both integrals should be correct.