# Regarding the convergence rate of function and variable in continuous mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423032/302797), I would like to know what is the relation between the convergence speed of a sequence and that of the function of the sequence. Are they at the same convergence speed?

For instance, if we assume that $\{x_k\}$ satisfies $x_k - x_0 = O\left(\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right)$ as $k → ∞$, i.e. quadratic convergence rate, where $x_0$ is the limiting point, and $f$ is a Lipschitz-continuous function, then is the convergence rate of $\{f(x_k)\}$ still quadratic? I.e.,$$
|f(x_k) - f(x_0)| = O\left( \frac{1}{k^2} \right). \quad (k → ∞)
$$
If not, what further assumption do we need to guarantee the same convergence order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of  Lipschitz, there is some $K$ such that $|f(x_k) - f(x_0)| \le K |x_k - x_0|$.  So if $x_k - x_0$ is $O(anything)$, so is $f(x_k) - f(x_0)$.

Comment: Yes, this problem can be solved by defination of Lipschitz. Thanks