# Continuous mapping theorem and convergence in $L_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, asymptotics, rate-of-convergence

My question kind of generalizes the question in [Analogue of continuous mapping theorem for convergence in $L_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423032/70762)
and it is related to the answer by [Nate Eldredge](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/822/nate-eldredge).

**Edited to give more details:**
Suppose that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
E|X_n - X|^p = O(b_{p,n}),
\end{equation}
where $p \geq 1$ and $b_{p,n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Furthermore, assume that there exist constants $0 < a < b < \infty$ such that $a \leq X_n \leq b $ *a.e.* and $a \leq X \leq b$ *a.e.*

Now, let $g$ be a continuous function with the following property: there exists a constant $C>0$ where $\sup_{x\in(a,b)}|g(x)| < C$. For example, $g(x) = x^r$, $r>0$, is a possible function. In this case, what can I say about $E|g(X_n) - g(X)|^p$, $p\geq1$? Is it possible to find a rate of convergence based on \eqref{eq1} and the above mentioned assumptions?

In a more specific case, is it possible to find the rate of convergence for $E|X_n^r - X^r|^p$, with $r > 0$ and $p \geq 1$, assuming \eqref{eq1} and that $a < X_n < b$ *a.e.* and $a<X<b$ *a.e.*?

Since $a < X_n < b$ *a.e.* and $a<X<b$ *a.e.*, I think that I can assume, as discussed by [Nate](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/822/nate-eldredge), that $L_p$ convergence is guaranteed (we have that $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in measure by the continuous mapping theorem, and in $L_p$ by the dominated convergence theorem), but I could not find any rate of convergence in my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I don't think continuity of g guarantees its boundedness. However, if you assume boundedness, then one can approximate g in $L^p$ norm by a Lipschitz function and recover rates of convergence.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan, I assume boundedness (although I known $g$ may not be in the whole line) because $X_n$ and $X$ are bounded a.e. For example, $g(x)=x^r, r>0$ is assumed to be bounded a.e. because it will be evaluated in an interval a.e. Based on this, do you think $E|g(X_n)-g(X)|^p$ can have the same rate of convergence as the one I have for $E|X_n-X|^p$? I tried to derive it, but I couldn't.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bounded a.e."? Do you maybe mean *uniformly bounded* a.e.?

Comment: @PhoemueX, perhaps it is not appropriate to say that the random variables are bounded _a.e._ I actually mean that there exist constants $0<a<b<\infty$ such that $a<X_n<b$ _a.e._ and $a<X<b$ _a.e._ But I think this assumption ensures that $g$ is (uniformly) bounded _a.e._, right? I'm not an expert in Math, so please let me know if you think I should reformulate my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a continuous function on a compact set is Lipschitz,
$$
\mathsf{E}|g(X_n)-g(X)|^p\le L^p\mathsf{E}|X_n-X|^p=O(b_{p,n}),
$$
where $L$ is the corresponding Lipschitz constant.