# Continuous mapping theorem for convergence in $L^1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $K > 0$ such that $|f(x) -f(y)| \leq K \min\{1, |x-y|\}, x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Also $X_n \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\text{a.s.}} X$. I am trying to prove that $f(X_n) \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{L^1} f(X)$.

We have that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $K$: $|f(x) -f(y)| \leq K |x-y|$ because $0\leq \min\{1, |x-y|\} \leq 1$. From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423667/634171), I started with
$$\mathbb{E}[|f(X_n) - f(X)|] \leq K \mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]$$
but I don't know that the RHS goes to 0. Many thanks!

Comment: Is it a conjecture or do you know that it is true and you need a proof?

Comment: @user940347 I know this is true but I'm stuck on bounding $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[|f(X_n) - f(X)|]=0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption on $f$ implies
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)-f(X)] \le K \mathbb{E}[\min(|X_n-X|,1)]
$$
The term in the expectation is bounded and converges a.s. to zero. By Lebesgue dominated convergence to expectation converges to zero, which proves to claim.